# Node.js call a function after n seconds of script runtime

Tags: node.js

I have a script in node.js and I want to call my end() function n seconds after the start of another function (or the start of the script).
So I tried using `setTimeout(function() {this.end()}, n);` for this, but setTimeout just acts as a sleep, which is bad and not what I wanted to achieve.

The scenario:

```
class Myclass {

constructor() {
    this.doStuff();
}

doStuff() {
    //Does stuff until ended by end()
}

end() {
    //ends doStuff(), end() is usually called by the user but sometimes the user does not and I don't want doStuff() to run indefinitely so I need to kill it after n seconds
}}
```

Comment: Add some more code, covering the complete scenario you described..

Comment: It's not what you ask but you can directly write `setTimeout(this.end, n);`
And setTimeout does not work as a sleep, it will add this.end to the nodeJS queue which is used by the event loop.

Comment: I don't see any `setTimeout` code in your code snippet. Where did you put that?

Comment: into the constructor, right before this.doStuff();